# Django redirect with non-URL parameter

Tags: python, django

I have a view

```
class FooDetailView(View):
    def get(request, *args):
        foo_id = int(args[0])
        foo = Foo.objects.get(pk=foo_id)
        // do something and render the page
```

And now I would like to add some message into this page. For example

```
class FooFuncView(View):
    def get(request):
        // do something
        return redirect('foo-detail', foo_id, 'call Func successfully')
```

Since my `urls.py` is simply

```
url(r'^foo-detail/([1-9][0-9]*)/', FooDetailView.as_view(),
  name='foo-detail'),
```

I get the error message becuase no reverse match

```
Reverse for 'foo-detail' with arguments '(<id>, 'call Func successfully')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tournament-detail/contestant/([1-9][0-9]*)/']
```

But I dont want the message shown in the url because it could be too long. I just want to simply render the page as `FooDetailView` does, and add extra message after different operation. It there any good way to achieve this? If not, any explantions for that?

Comment: Consider using the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/) instead of trying to pass messages through URL parameters.

Comment: Oh you're trying to pass in a second param. Use django's messaging framework. You add messages to a user's session and the messages are automatically deleted once you read them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the already mentioned messages framework in your case:

```
from django.contrib import messages

class FooFuncView(View):
    def get(request):
        // do something
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'call Func successfully')
        return redirect('foo-detail', foo_id)
```

The text will be available in the template context of the page that is requested in the redirect.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages):

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

If you are using [django-bootstrap](http://django-bootstrap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you can just add the following snippet into your base template:

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts #}
{% bootstrap_messages %}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you return a redirect, you are simply telling the browser to go to the new url, e.g. `/foo/1/`. You can't include a message like `'call Func successfully'` if it isn't part of the URL.

If you don't want to store the message (or a message code) in the URL, then you need to store it somewhere else, for example in the session.

Since this is a common requirement, Django includes the [messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/) to do this.